# if $T$ is isomorphism, how can I prove that $[T^{-1}]_B=[T]_B^{-1}$ for any base $B$ of $V$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, vector-space-isomorphism

given vector space $V$ so that $\dim(V)$ is finite , and linear-transformation $T:V \to V$.

if $T$ is isomorphism, how can I prove that $[T^{-1}]_B=[T]_B^{-1}$ for any base $B$ of $V$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using thae fact that$$[T]_B.[T^{-1}]_B=[T.T^{-1}]_B=\operatorname{Id}.$$

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you explain me just why $[I]_B = I $?

Comment: If $B=\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ then, for each $i\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, $\operatorname{Id}.v_i=v_i$. Therefore, the matrix of $\operatorname{Id}$ with respect to $B$ is the identity matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Use the definition of $[T]_B$. Remember that if $[v]_B$ is the (column) vector whose entries are the coordinates of $v$ in the base $B$, then $[T]_B$ is the $n\times n$ matrix such that
$$[T]_B\cdot [v]_B=[T(v)]_B, \quad \forall v\in V,$$
that is the (only) matrix such that when it premultiplies $[v]_B$ gives a (column) vector whose entries are the coordinates of $T(v) \in V$ in the base $B$.

Now, what would the matrix $[T^{-1}]_B$ be?

Answer (score 0):

$T\circ T^{-1}=I_V$, so $[T]_B [ T^{-1}]_B=I$·